# Jquery problems from back-end when users want to reset password?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi and thanks for taking the time to read this post,

I have absolutely zero experience with coding. My friend and I are in the process of starting a business, an app based service, and have run into a problem with the setup that we have serving our users.

We currently do not have access to our IT capacity as he is finishing his Master's Thesis. Therefore, we are looking for your guidance.

Users are currently unable to reset their password. When they try to update their password on a site created on the back end, nothing happens.

[This is what it looks like in Chrome's Network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NXvR.png)

From what I can gather, the setup is on an Apache PHP server, using html/css/javascript. I have no other knowledge of it, but I have access to the server.

This is the code in the forgot.js file:

```html
var url_string = window.location.href

var params = parse_query_string(url_string);
console.log(params)

checkExpire()

if (params.length == 0) {
    error()
}

if (params.token.length == undefined) {

}

if (params.token.length == 0) {
    error()
}

function error() {
    $(".login h2").text("Your link isnt working")
    $(".loginForm").css("display", "none")
}

$("#loginForm").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    createPassword()
})

$("#loginButton").click(function () {
    createPassword()
})

function checkExpire() {
    var settings = getSettings("/expire/" + params.token, "GET", "")
    b = false
    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        if (response.success) {
            return
        } else {
            $(".login h2").text("Your link has expired")
            $(".loginForm").css("display", "none")
        }
    });
}

function createPassword() {
    $("#loginResponse").text("")
    password = $("#password").val()
    repassword = $("#repassword").val()
    c = true

    if (password.length == 0) {
        $("#password_label").css("color", "rgb(204, 0, 0)")
        c = false
    } else {
        $("#password_label").css("color", "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)")
    }

    if (repassword.length == 0) {
        $("#repassword_label").css("color", "rgb(204, 0, 0)")
        c = false
    } else {
        $("#repassword_label").css("color", "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)")
    }

    if (repassword != password) {
        $("#loginResponse").text("Passwords matcher ikke")
        $("#password_label").css("color", "rgb(204, 0, 0)")
        $("#repassword_label").css("color", "rgb(204, 0, 0)")
        c = false
    } else {
        $("#password_label").css("color", "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)")
        $("#repassword_label").css("color", "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)")
    }

    if (c) {
        var data = { "password": password, "token": params.token }
        var settings = getSettings("/password", "POST", data)
        b = false
        $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            if (response.success) {
                $("#loginResponse").text(response.msg)
            } else {
                showToast("Error in creating password")
            }
        });
    }
}

function getSettings(path, method, data) {
    return {
        "url": url + path,
        "method": method,
        "timeout": 0,
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        "data": JSON.stringify(data)
    };
}

var snackbarContainer = document.querySelector('#toastMaster');

function showToast(msg) {
    var data = { message: msg, timeout: 5000 };
    snackbarContainer.MaterialSnackbar.showSnackbar(data);
}

function parse_query_string(query) {
    var vars = query.split("?");
    var query_string = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
        var pair = vars[i].split("=");
        var key = decodeURIComponent(pair[0]);
        var value = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
        // If first entry with this name
        if (typeof query_string[key] === "undefined") {
            query_string[key] = decodeURIComponent(value);
            // If second entry with this name
        } else if (typeof query_string[key] === "string") {
            var arr = [query_string[key], decodeURIComponent(value)];
            query_string[key] = arr;
            // If third or later entry with this name
        } else {
            query_string[key].push(decodeURIComponent(value));
        }
    }
    return query_string;
}
```

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: From the network tab it appears that the error is in the back-end code so it causes server side error.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Do you have any idea of where to look to fix it?

Comment: No, Because it's mostly in the back-end and you didn't share the back-end code that causes that error.